# Where can I learn how to create a files app style file selection UI in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

[image]

I want to implement a file selection screen UI like the one you see in the recents sections of the native files app, but for the love of God, I can't find any useful information across many different websites and youtube tutorials. I learned about UITableViews, CustomTableViewCells, HStack, VStack, and ZStack, but none of them seem to replicate the behavior shown in the files app. I tried to use CustomTableViewCells, but I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the lines. **Does anyone know the solution to these two problems: How to get rid of lines in UITableView and How to automatically adjust the height of each cell by calculating how large the description text is vertically.** An even better solution would be if there is a new ViewController type that I'm not aware of that displays files like the files app recents screen, but if there isn't one, please don't bother. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Just use two images. One with a check mark selected and another unselected with transparent background. Add this image on top of your cell thumbnail

Comment: Regarding your last question. You can take a look at [UIDocumentBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller) but it is not customizable AFAIK